# How to get width of selected item HTHorizontalSelectionList

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Is there any possible way to get width of selected HTHorizontalSelectionList item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is view then `insatnceOfView.frame.size.width` will give you width